# openpose compilation tells libopenpose.so: undefined references to `op::renderPartAffinityFieldGpu(...t)'

Tags: caffe, opencv3.0

my configuration is:

```
Openpose:latest(2017-05-29) master branch
Caffe   :latest(2017-05-29) master branch
OpenCV  :3.1
Ubuntu  16.04 64bit
GCC     :5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
```

I want to try openpose in my laptop with an AMD video card,so I disable CUDA,and enabled opencv 3 in caffe Makefile.config like this:

```
CPU_ONLY := 1
OPENCV_VERSION := 3
```

After compiled caffe,

```
cp openpose/3rdparty/caffe/Makefile.config openpose/
```

then

```
make all -j 10
```

got these:

```
CXX/LD -o .build_release/examples/tutorial_thread/1_openpose_read_and_display.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/examples/tutorial_thread/3_user_input_processing_and_output.bin
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `op::renderPartAffinityFieldGpu(float*, op::PoseModel, cv::Size_<int> const&, float const*, cv::Size_<int> const&, float, int, float)'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `op::renderBodyPartsGpu(float*, op::PoseModel, cv::Size_<int> const&, float const*, cv::Size_<int> const&, float, float)'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `void op::connectBodyPartsGpu<float>(op::Array<float>&, float*, float const*, float const*, op::PoseModel, cv::Size_<int> const&, int, int, float, int, float, float)'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `void op::connectBodyPartsGpu<double>(op::Array<double>&, double*, double const*, double const*, op::PoseModel, cv::Size_<int> const&, int, int, double, int, double, double)'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `op::renderBodyPartGpu(float*, op::PoseModel, cv::Size_<int> const&, float const*, cv::Size_<int> const&, float, int, float)'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `cudaGetErrorString'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `cudaFree'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `void op::resizeAndMergeGpu<double>(double*, double const*, std::array<int, 4ul> const&, std::array<int, 4ul> const&, double)'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `cudaPeekAtLastError'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `op::renderHandsGpu(float*, cv::Size_<int> const&, float const*, int, float)'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `void op::nmsGpu<float>(float*, int*, float const*, float, std::array<int, 4ul> const&, std::array<int, 4ul> const&)'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `cudaMalloc'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `cudaMemcpy'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `void op::resizeAndMergeGpu<float>(float*, float const*, std::array<int, 4ul> const&, std::array<int, 4ul> const&, float)'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `op::renderFaceGpu(float*, cv::Size_<int> const&, float const*, int, float)'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `void op::nmsGpu<double>(double*, int*, double const*, double, std::array<int, 4ul> const&, std::array<int, 4ul> const&)'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `op::renderPoseGpu(float*, op::PoseModel, int, cv::Size_<int> const&, float const*, bool, bool, float)'
.build_release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined references to `op::renderPartAffinityFieldsGpu(float*, op::PoseModel, cv::Size_<int> const&, float const*, cv::Size_<int> const&, float, float)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:492: die Regel für Ziel „.build_release/examples/tutorial_thread/3_user_input_processing_and_output.bin“ scheiterte
make: *** [.build_release/examples/tutorial_thread/3_user_input_processing_and_output.bin] Fehler 1
make: *** Auf noch nicht beendete Prozesse wird gewartet …
```

It seems that example code still use cuda/gpu related stuff,is that right?How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, but you cannot disable GPU for OpenPose (nor the Caffe that OpenPose will use).

The CPU code of OpenPose is not finished (and not expected to be finished at the moment given the very slow speed). You will have to use CUDA + cuDNN. Hence, a machine with a NVIDIA graphics card.